# Using docker to run a distributed computation

Tags: docker, distributed-computing

I just came across docker, and was looking through its docs to figure out how to use this to distribute a java project across multiple nodes, while making this distribution platform independent i.e the nodes can be running any platform. Currently i'm sending classes to different nodes and running it on them with the assumption that these nodes have the same environment as the client. I couldn't quite figure out how to do this, any suggestions wouldbe greatly appreciated.

Comment: Docker does not provide the ability to run projects on different platforms. Docket by itself run on Linux only. You can run it on other platforms but you need virtualization to run Linux inside a virtual machine and run Docker there.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar. In my humble opinion Docker or not is not your biggest problem. However, using Docker images for this purpose can and will save you a lot of headaches.

We have a build pipeline where a very large Java project is built using Maven. The outcome of this is a single large JAR file that contains the software we need to run on our nodes.

But some of our nods also need to run some 3rd party software such as Zookeeper and Cassandra. So after the Maven build we use packer.io to create a Docker image that contains all needed components which ends up on a web server that can be reached only from within our private cloud infrastructure.

If we want to roll out our system we use a combination of Python scripts that talk with the OpenStack API and create virtual machines on our cloud, and Puppet which performs the actual software provisioning inside of the VMs. Our VMs are CentOS 7 images, so what Puppet actually does is to add the Docker yum repos. Then installs Docker through yum, pulls in the Docker image from our repository server and finally uses a custom bash script to launch our Docker image.

For each of these steps there are certainly even more elegant ways of doing it.